# Advantage of RTSP over HTTP for ip cam streaming

Tags: http, rtsp, ip-camera

I recently bought an ip cam for a project. So my project was just to create a button on a webpage to show the video feed coming from the cam when clicked on it. If i have to stream the rtsp link of the ip cam via a browser, i need to use  ffmpeg for converting into HLS. But when i use a http video link of the cam, its easy and convenient. So my question is, what advantage does rtsp have over http ? and what method should i choose in a industrial project.  At the moment i have successfully implemented the button with http video link and it works. I was just curious to know the advantage i will have if i use rtsp. Thanks a lot for you precious time.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on the network environment that you are dealing with. For sure using dash/HLS will result in higher latency but on the other hand using TCP for streaming is easier to go through the firewalls.

Apple reasoning for introducing RTSP over HTTP:

> Using standard RTSP/RTP it is possible to stream a presentation to a user via a single
> TCP connection. (See RFC 2036 “Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP)”, section 10.12)
> Unfortunately, that is not sufficient to reach a significant population of Internet users.
> These users are typically on private IP networks where the client machines have indirect
> access to the public Internet via email and HTTP Proxies.
> The QuickTime HTTP transport exploits the capability of HTTP GET and POST
> methods to carry an indefinite amount of data in their reply, and message body
> respectively. In the most simple case, the client makes a HTTP GET request to the
> streaming server to open the server to client channel. Then the client makes a POST
> request to the server to open the client to server channel.

[Link](https://opensource.apple.com/source/QuickTimeStreamingServer/QuickTimeStreamingServer-412.42/Documentation/RTSP_Over_HTTP.pdf)